# Is there any reference about the half-trace when m is even in F(2^m)

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field

There is a algorithm listed in [D.1.6, Algorithm 3](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/grouper.ieee.org/groups/1363/private/x9-62-09-20-98.pdf), it seems that it is used to solve the quadratic equation when $m$ is even in $F(2^m)$. However, I can not find any reference about this algorithm, as well as the definition about half-trace when $m$ is even. Can anyone introduce some basic ideas or reference about this algorithm, many thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good reference for this include section II.2.4 of [Elliptic Curves in Cryptography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01CEKKKDU) (Blake, Seroussi, Smart) or section 11.2.6 of the [Handbook of elliptic and hyperelliptic curve cryptography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584885181) (Cohen and Frey).

For completeness, I'll give a brief overview of quaddratic equation in characteristic 2. In fields of characteristic 2, quadratic equations can be converted by a linear change of variable to one of the two forms
$$x^2+\beta=0$$
$$x^2+x+\beta=0.$$
In the first case there is a single repeated root and by the field equation $X^{2^m}-X=0$ we can compute this as $x=\beta^{2^{m-1}}$.

In the second case there will be no roots or two roots of the form $z$ and $z+1$ because $(z+1)^2+(z+1)=z^2+z$. If we take the trace of $x^2+x+\beta$ we see get $\mathrm{Tr}(x^2)+\mathrm Tr(x)+\mathrm{Tr}(\beta)=\mathrm{Tr}(x)+\mathrm Tr(x)+\mathrm{Tr}(\beta)=\mathrm{Tr}(\beta)$ and so we can see that the two root case corresponds to equations with $\mathrm{Tr}(\beta)=0$.

For odd $m$ we note that the equation could be written
$$x^2+x=\mathrm{Tr}(\beta)+\beta=\beta^{2^{m-1}}+\beta^{2^{m-2}}+\cdots+\beta^2$$
$$=(\beta^{2^m-2})^2+(\beta^{2^m-4})^2+\cdots+(\beta^2)^2+\beta^{2^m-2}+\cdots+\beta^2$$
$$=(\beta^{2^m-2}+\beta^{2^m-4}+\cdots+\beta^2)^2+(\beta^{2^m-2}+\beta^{2^m-4}+\cdots+\beta^2)$$
so that we may take $x=\beta^{2^m-2}+\beta^{2^m-4}+\cdots+\beta^2$ for one solution (and add 1 of the other).

For even $m$ we require an auxiliary element $\tau$ of trace 1 so that
$$x^2+x=\tau\mathrm{Tr}(\beta)+\beta\mathrm{Tr}(\tau)=$$
$$=\tau(\beta^{2^{m-1}}+\beta^{2^{m-2}}+\cdots+\beta^2)+\beta(\tau^{2^{m-1}}+\cdots+\tau^2)$$
$$=(\beta^{2^{m-2}}\tau^{2^{m-1}}+\beta^{2^{m-3}}(\tau^{2^{m-1}}+\tau^{2^{m-2}})+\cdots+\beta(\tau^{2^{m-1}}+\cdots+\tau^2))^2+(\beta^{2^{m-2}}\tau^{2^{m-1}}+\beta^{2^{m-3}}(\tau^{2^{m-1}}+\tau^{2^{m-2}})+\cdots+\beta(\tau^{2^{m-1}}+\cdots+\tau^2))$$
allowing us to take $x=\beta^{2^{m-2}}\tau^{2^{m-1}}+\beta^{2^{m-3}}(\tau^{2^{m-1}}+\tau^{2^{m-2}})+\cdots+\beta(\tau^{2^{m-1}}+\cdots+\tau^2)$ as one solution (adding 1 for the other).

Algorithm 3 above chooses a random $\tau$, efficiently computes the above expression as $z$ while computing $w=\tau\mathrm{Tr}(\beta)$ at the same time. At step 4 it checks to see if $w=0$ and if so deduces that $\mathrm{Tr}(\beta)=0$ and a solution can exist. At step 6 it tests if $z^2+z=\tau(\mathrm{Tr}(\beta)+\beta(\mathrm{Tr}(\tau)=0$. If this is the case, then $\mathrm{Tr}(\tau)=0$ and we must try again. As 50% of elements have non-zero trace, we should not need many attempts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation!